# Is parse.com a fairly substandard method of creating backend databases for android applications?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, parse-platform

i have become quite good at using parse.com for remote databases in android studio, for android apps, which hasn't been all that difficult. Do professional, high quality android apps mainly use php and mysql for remote database interaction, what are the advantages of using php and mysql over something like parse, what is JSON also?

Comment: In answer to your question *"Do professional, high quality android apps... use Parse"*  Yes, many large well-known ("professional") dotcoms use Parse or other baas.  But this question is just too messy for the board here; and you can't just throw in things like "by the way what is json?"  :)  So let's delete this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to re-word your question. "Substandard" is possibly subjective.

While I don't have direct experience with Parse, it is not designed to be a cheap solution. "High quality" apps do not necessarily use "php and mysql" although some do.

This is a question of "buy" vs. "build" and many apps with sufficient funding, skill set and ego will build in order to have control of the platform. It is more time consuming and expensive to build your own, but it allows you to customize the features and functionality of your backend. Parse allows for customization, with a fee. Each app/organization would need to weight the cost/benefit of the "buy" / "build" decision.

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation http://www.json.org/) is simply a way to organize object data into a string. This is particularly convenient for data transmission over HTTP. It has a syntax, etc. to allow you to serialize/deserialize objects and basically communicate structured data. It is only "special" because people use it a lot, which makes it very portable.